# Consistency between Mongo and Cassandra read/write operation

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, cassandra

I have to create an application using spring/spring boot in which I need to read data from mongo db and write into Cassandra db.

During this operation, I need to make sure if I successfully write rows to Cassandra then I should also update status in mongodb for the same row to "processed" to represent data is being inserted in cassandra successfully. E.g. As an end goal, if I have 100 rows in mongodb and if I am able to insert only 99 rows successfully in Cassandra then I should update 99 rows in mongo db as well to represents rows are processed and I need to ignore 1 row which is not be inserted in Cassandra and in mongo its status should be current("pending") only.

So I think I need to handle it using Transaction like semantics so that for each record either I commit in both DB's or no commit for a row(in case of any issues) so that state in consistent.

Since I am relatively new to mongo and Cassandra:

Can someone please share with me the transaction like semantic which can help me in the above scenario?

Any other suggestions would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: This question as it stands is a bit too broad and asking for recommendations.

Comment: @Andrew: I have made this questions specific. Can you help now?